# Wrap each command in a rescue statement

Tags: ruby, selenium, exception

I have 10 Ruby function calls I'd like to execute and each call could possibly throw an exception. I'd like to handle each exception the same way and continue. Is there a way to do this without wrapping each line in a `begin` ... `rescue` ... `end` block?

[Edit]: Use case for this is a screen scraper/automation tool that uses the Selenium web driver to fill out forms. I don't want to bother checking if options in select elements exist, just fill them out as good as possible. for this, I need to call `Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.select_by` and continue if it throws a "cannot locate option with value x" exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean something like this ?

```
class Wtf
  def f1
    raise "f1"
  end
  def f2
    raise "f2"
  end
end

obj= Wtf.new

[:f1, :f2].each do |f|
  begin
    obj.send f
  rescue Exception=> e
    p e
  end
end
```

Edit: added more code to the example

Answer (score 7):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2660382/130121) which also does what I want:

```
def action
    yield
    rescue
        ....
    ensure
        ....
end

action { call1 }
action { call2 }
action { call3 }
```

Comment: This looks like a more general, reusable solution!

Answer (score 2):

I like qwned's approach with #send, but it's not ideal for situations where not all of the methods will be called sequentially.

Continuations are well-suited to this sort of thing:

```
require 'continuation'

class Continuer

  # Define five methods for testing
  (1..5).each { |i| define_method("method#{i}") { puts "method#{i} called" } }

  def do_these_things
    cc = nil
    callcc { |c| cc = c; method1; }
    callcc { |c| cc = c; method2; raise }
    # Do other things right here, maybe...
    callcc { |c| cc = c; method3; raise }
    callcc { |c| cc = c; method4; }
    callcc { |c| cc = c; method5; }
  rescue
    puts 'Caught exception.  Continuing.'
    cc.call
  end

end

Continuer.new.do_these_things
```

This works by recording a continuation in the 'cc' variable when executing each failure-prone method.  The rescue statement then simply resumes at that continuation.  It's sort of like a goto statement with a dynamic label.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
begin
  do_something
  do_something_else
  do_do_do
rescue Exception1 => e
  # error handling
rescue Exception2 => e
  # error handling
```

if do_something throws and exception the others calls won't be called. And I think is nicer than doing lots of `begin.. rescue` blocks. Just handle different exceptions.

Comment: The statements all throw the same exception and I want them all executed. So unfortunately this is not a valid answer :(

Comment: ok, but then it's depends on you need. Do you want to handle each failure differently? Why not enclose them in a single rescue block? I'm guessing that you want to know "where" the exception was thrown, so you should try to change some "state" after each function (or within) and then query that state in the rescue block

Answer (score 0):

```
def f1; raise "X"; end
def f2; raise "Y"; end
#...
funcList = [:f1,:f2,...]
funcList.each{|f|
     begin
       send(f)
     rescue Exception => e
        #handle
     end
 }
```